# unresolved external symbol is due to .lib or .dll?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, static-libraries, linker-errors

I'm struggling to try to use OpenEXR in my Visual Studio 2015 project.

The OpenEXR library is successfully built. But when I build my project, I got unresolved symbol error.

I suppose the error is due to the linker failing to find the library. But I don't know if it's in .lib or .dll?

I've googled for this and it is said that for static libraries, the implementation is all in `.lib` file.

But for dynamically linked libraries, the implementation is in `.dll` file. So which caused the unresolved symbol error? `.lib` or `.dll`?

Error:

```
7>core.lib(ImageIO.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned short const * const half::_eLut" (?_eLut@half@@0QBGB) referenced in function "bool __cdecl Tungsten::ImageIO::saveExr(class Tungsten::Path const &,float const *,int,int,int)" (?saveExr@ImageIO@Tungsten@@YA_NAEBVPath@2@PEBMHHH@Z)
```

Comment: Just google for the symbol name, lots of programmers have this linker error.  OpenEXR itself uses a library, libHalf.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the comment. But I want to figure out the possible reason of the problem. Since `LNK2019` is due to the linker cannot find an implementation. But I don't know if the implementation is in `.lib` or `.dll`, so I cannot figure out it. If I know, the problem might be solved myself. But thanks for the suggestion, I will look for other related answer.

Comment: The linker only ever links a .lib file, never a .dll.  There are two kinds of .lib files, a static library and an import library.  And import library describes what a DLL exports, it is small.  A static library contains code, it is not small.  The linker error is enough to see that this is not an import library.  Linking a static library also requires linking any other library that the code depends on.  Like libHalf.

Comment: @HansPassant I wonder why you think `the linker error is enough to see that this is not an import library`? I have the `Half.lib` installed, and it is 6KB in size, while it has a corresponding `Half.dll`, which is 270KB... The weird thing is I include the library path in VS but still no magic.

Comment: Since this is a static library, you'll also need the static library for Half, not its import library.  Maybe you meant to build the DLL version of openexr, hard to guess.

Comment: @HansPassant OK. I think you're right. I follow exactly the install guide of Ilmbase, however. Seems the default setting is generating a dynamic library. But does it matter if I build the static library as a dynamic one?